# Angular 2 Checkbox value

Tags: angular, checkbox

I created a table of players class (fullname, position and ranking), the table has c checkbox for each raw. How can I implement so when I click on the checkbox, the value of the player (for that raw) will appear in the html?

the HTML code:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let player of bullsPlayers; let i = index;">
      <td>{{player.fullName}}</td>
      <td>{{player.position}}</td>
      <td>{{player.ranking}}</td>
      <td>
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          class="form-check-input" 
          [id]="bullsPlayers[i]" 
          [name]="bullsPlayers[i]"
          value="player.fullName" 
          (change)="addOrRemoveBullsPlayer($event.target.value)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    
<div>{{selectedBullsPlayers}} </div>
```

TS code (only related lines):

```ts
bullsPlayers = [];
selectedBullsPlayers = [];
    
constructor(private _playerService: PlayerService) {}
    
ngOnInit (){
  this._playerService.getPlayers()
    .then(players => this.players = players)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  this._playerService.getBullsPlayers()
    .then(players => this.bullsPlayers = players)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
    
addOrRemoveBullsPlayer(value: string) {
  var indexOfEntry = this.selectedBullsPlayers.indexOf(value);
  if(indexOfEntry < 0) {
    this.selectedBullsPlayers.push(value);
  } else {
    this.selectedBullsPlayers.splice(indexOfEntry, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by the value of the player ?

Comment: for example - it's full name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ngModel` directive and bind it to `player.selected`

html:

```
<td>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="form-check-input"
    [id]="bullsPlayers[i]"
    [name]="bullsPlayers[i]"
    [(ngModel)]="player.selected"
    value="player.fullName"
    (change)="updateBullsPlayer()"/>
</td>
```

component.ts:

```
updateBullsPlayer() {
  this.selectedBullsPlayers = selectedBullsPlayers.filter((item) => item.selected)
}
```

don't worry about `selected` field it will added automatically by `ngModel`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
        value="player.fullName"
```

to

```
        [value]="player.fullName"
```

Oh, and change your display div into something like

```
        <div *ngFor="let playerFullName of selectedBullsPlayers">{{playerFullName}}</div>
```